# Cap deploy assets precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am setting up new staging server for my application. Existing staging, as well as development environments with the same release versions work fine.

Trying to `cap deploy`, I receive the following error:

```
    [1906b0ea] Command: cd /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.0 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
rake aborted!
...
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'datatables' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib
  /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756/app/assets/images
  /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.3.0/app/assets/images
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.3.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.3.0/app/assets/media
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-3.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts
  /home/user/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756/vendor/assets/bower_components
  /home/user/appname/releases/20160831113756/tmp/themes
      /home/user/ap
```

pname/releases/20160831113756/vendor/assets/bower_components

Here is my `application.js` file
            //

```
= require jquery
            //= require jquery_ujs
            //= require datatables
            //= require turbolinks
            //= require cocoon
            //= require select2
            //= require highcharts
            //= require highcharts/highcharts-more
            //= require sparklines
            //= require rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider
            //= require Sortable
            //= require moment
            //= require pikaday
            //= require tooltipster
            //= require urijs
            //= require jscolor/jscolor
            //= require_tree .
```

And here are parts of `Gemfile.lock`

```
    jquery-datatables-rails (3.3.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1)
      sass-rails
   ....
       ajax-datatables-rails (0.3.1)
      railties (>=
```

3.1)

I've searched several SO questions, but none seem to be relevant.

Do you have any ideas on what could cause that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the `jquery-datatables-rails` gem.

I looked at the [README](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails#general-installation) for that gem, and the installation instructions say the correct way to reference it as follows:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```